# Symfony, output form field more than once

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a tabbed form and I want to output a form field more than once. Say I have a tab called "individual" and another called "company". In the first tab I want to have the fields "name"and "address". In the second tab I want to have the fields "company" and "address", so I want to show the address form field twice (the user would select if they are an individual or a company by selecting the tab). But when I try to do this Symfony will not render the second address field because it has already been output.

Is there a way to override this behavior and have symfony output this field twice?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately it seems that Symfony2 ( at least v2.2 and 2.3 ) only allow to render a form once because of Symfony2 form's internal handling ( token, id etc ).
The only way I have found is "tinkering", use twig set to capture form into a twig variable and then you will be able to use it more than once, ex :

```
{% set twig_form %}
<form method="POST" name="payment" action="{{ url('form_action') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
   <label>My label</label>{{form_widget(form.input)}}
   {{form_widget(form._token)}}
{% endset %}
{{twig_form}}
   <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
<div>...</div>
{{twig_form}}
   <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```